# C double to long conversion loses value in some cases - why?

Tags: c

I have the following code, which is causing me a weird double to long conversion problem.  Under the hood, `logCpof` just writes to a special log file, using `vprintf`.  In my example below, the top one works, but the bottom one does not.  That said, I have other examples where it is reversed, or where both fail.

```
    psMbo->mbonum4 = (long)(psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100);
    logCpof( psMbo->mbocpo, "Num4 %ld from %.*s, %f * 100 = %f (%ld)",
        psMbo->mbonum4,
        str_len(psXmlRequest->zTotalOutstanding), psXmlRequest->zTotalOutstanding,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100,
        (long)(psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100 ) );
...
    psMbo->mbonum5 = (long)(psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100);
    logCpof( psMbo->mbocpo, "Num5 %ld from %.*s, %f * 100 = %f (%ld)",
        psMbo->mbonum5,
        str_len(psXmlRequest->zTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney),
            psXmlRequest->zTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100,
        (long)(psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100 ) );
```

This gives the following log:

```
xmlCli 184906:Num4 34079 from 340.79, 340.790000 * 100 = 34079.000000 (34079)
xmlCli 184906:Num5 37294 from 372.95, 372.950000 * 100 = 37295.000000 (37294)
```

So how does double 37295.000 become long 27394?  The conversion from double to long seems to be decremented by 1.  As I implied above, it does not happen with all doubles, just with some doubles.  For instance, double 34079.00 becomes long 34079, as I would expect.  The LONG_MAX is 2147483647, so my new long is considerably smaller than that.  As such, I don't see how it could be hitting some weird max.

I did run my code through `valgrind`, but that did not reveal any memory issues related to this section of code.  That said, it did consistently work better.  Any ideas?

Edit 4/15/2022 to answer comments:

First of all, some things that are not obvious from my code snippet:

```
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding = strtod(
            psXmlRequest->zTotalOutstanding, &pzTail );
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney = strtod(
            psXmlRequest->zTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney, &pzTail );
```

`zTotalOutstanding` and `zTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney` are both 101 character text fields filled from an XML file.  Not a huge deal, just not obvious from my code, and this is why I use `%.*s` in my log statement.

Secondly, and also not obvious from the code, but mbonum4 and mbonum5 are long fields (actually goes to a MySql table with columns of type `int(11)`, but this is a side issue).  No more doubles in the structure, and we need to preserve 2 decimal places, so thus the `* 100`.  Not elegant, but works just fine most of the time.  This is one of the few situations where it does not work.

Finally, this is my changed code based on @Eric Postpischil comments:

```
    psMbo->mbonum4 = (long)(psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100);
    logCpof( psMbo->mbocpo,
        "Num4 %ld from %.*s, %f (AKA %.99g) * 100 = %f (%ld) or %.99g",
        psMbo->mbonum4,
        str_len(psXmlRequest->zTotalOutstanding), psXmlRequest->zTotalOutstanding,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100,
        (long)(psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100 ),
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100 );
    psMbo->mbonum5 = (long)(psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100);
    logCpof( psMbo->mbocpo,
        "Num5 %ld from %.*s, %f (AKA %.99g) * 100 = %f (%ld) or %.99g",
        psMbo->mbonum5,
        str_len(psXmlRequest->zTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney),
            psXmlRequest->zTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100,
        (long)(psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100 ),
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100 );
```

And here are the results, as requested:

```
xmlCli 135817:Num4 34079 from 340.79, 340.790000 (AKA 340.79000000000002046363078989088535308837890625) * 100 = 34079.000000 (34079) or 34079
xmlCli 135817:Num5 37294 from 372.95, 372.950000 (AKA 372.94999999999998863131622783839702606201171875) * 100 = 37295.000000 (37294) or 37295
```

So I guess the `372.94999999999998863131622783839702606201171875` proves that the double has extra information I am not seeing.  So, based on other comments, I guess I first need to round to 2 decimal places (normal rounding logic), and then `* 100`?  Or is there something else obvious I am missing.

Comment: What printf displays as 37295.000 might really be 37294.9999999 or something. See if you can print the entire value out, or better yet, look at the exact bytes yourself. When you convert to long, it floors rather than rounding, so you get 37294.

Comment: When converting from floating point to integer, it's best to use a rounding function rather than just casting. That will avoid this problem.

Comment: Change `"Num5 %ld from %.*s, %f * 100 = %f (%ld)"` to `"Num5 %ld from %.*s, %.99g * 100 = %.99g (%ld)"` and show the results.

Comment: What type does your `str_len()` return.  If it is `size_t`, that could be part of the problem as the `%.*s` expects an `int` and not a `size_t` for the `*`.  OTOH, it may be tangential, though it is something you'd clean for preference.  Note that the compiler cannot (or, at least, does not) automatically apply casts like `size_t` to `int` in the variadic part of the argument list (the `, ...` part of the argument list).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `str_len` returns `int`, and has never caused a problem with `%.*s` situations.  I have used this for logging 100s of times.  Other commenters: researching and will update post accordingly

Comment: If you have `extern int str_len(const char *str);` or equivalent, using it for the length specified via a `*` in a `printf()` format string won't cause problems. But we can't see that from your code, and the closely related function `strlen()` does return `size_t` and could, in theory, cause problems when used to supply a value to `*`. This is why we prefer to see an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same thing by another name.

Comment: Re “I guess I first need to round to 2 decimal places (normal rounding logic)”: Rounding to two decimal places will not work, because it is impossible. Literally, it is impossible to store 372.95 in the `double` format that your C implementation uses. It uses the IEEE-754 binar64 format, which represents finite numbers as an integer multiplied by a power of two (or mathematical equivalent). 372.95 does not equal any integer multiplied by any power of two. The nearest numbers it represents are 6,561,005,785,264,947•2^−44 and 6,561,005,785,264,948•2^−44.

Comment: Those numbers are 372.94999999999998863131622783839702606201171875 and 372.950000000000045474735088646411895751953125, and the former is closer to 372.95, so attempting to round to two decimal digits will yield 372.94999999999998863131622783839702606201171875 at best. If you know that some calculation perform with real-number arithmetic would yield a number x such that 100x would be an integer, then you can use calculate that integer with floating-point arithmetic by rounding **after** multiplying by 100, not before, provided the floating-point operations did not introduce excessive errors.

Comment: Figuring out whether the rounding errors in the floating-point operations might be too large requires knowledge of the floating-point format and its arithmetic, knowledge of the operations performed, and knowledge of the data operated on (such as the ranges of the numbers involved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you convert a floating point number to an integer (including a long), the C and C++ specs specify that the conversion truncates towards 0, rather than rounding to the nearest.  When you print a floating point number with limited precision (as you've done here with %f -- which prints to (just) 6 decimal places) it will round towards the nearest.

As a result, when you have a floating point number that is eg 5.9999999 the printf with %f will print 6.000000, while a conversion to int will give 5.

If you want to convert a float (or double) to the *nearest* integer you should use `round` -- eg: `(long)round(psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100.0)` in your example code.  The `round` function will round the double to the nearest integer, which will then be converted to a `long`

Answer (score 0):

My fix is as follows, based on the comments, especially from @Eric Postpischil:

```
    psMbo->mbonum4 = (long)RRND(psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100, 0);
    logCpof( psMbo->mbocpo,
        "Num4 %ld from %.*s, %.99g * 100 = %f, RRND %ld, %f",
        psMbo->mbonum4,
        str_len(psXmlRequest->zTotalOutstanding), psXmlRequest->zTotalOutstanding,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100,
        (long)RRND(psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100, 0 ),
        RRND(psXmlRequest->dTotalOutstanding * 100, 0 ));
...
    psMbo->mbonum5 = (long)RRND(
                    psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100, 0);
    logCpof( psMbo->mbocpo,
        "Num5 %ld from %.*s, %.99g * 100 = %f, RRND %ld, %f",
        psMbo->mbonum5,
        str_len(psXmlRequest->zTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney),
            psXmlRequest->zTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney,
        psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100,
        (long)RRND(psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100, 0 ),
        RRND(psXmlRequest->dTotalPriceSetPresentmentMoney * 100, 0 ));
```

where RRND function is defined as follows:

```
double RRND( double fnbr, double fexp )
{
    double scale = pow( (double)10.0, fexp );

    return( ( floor((double)( fnbr * scale ) + .5 ) ) / scale );
}
```

My final test results were:

```
xmlCli 180051:Num4 34079 from 340.79, 340.79000000000002046363078989088535308837890625 * 100 = 34079.000000, RRND 34079, 34079.000000
xmlCli 180051:Num5 37295 from 372.95, 372.94999999999998863131622783839702606201171875 * 100 = 37295.000000, RRND 37295, 37295.000000
```

It is weird because I have used code like `(long)<double value> * 100` many times with no visible problems.  I suspect in all those cases, we did not care if it was slightly off, and since it only happens in certain cases, we just never noticed.  We care in this case, so we noticed it, and were forced to fix it.  As per the advice in the comments, rounding after multiplying by 100 was the key.